# Не присваивается значение строке c#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Собственно сам вопрос, есть строка которой должно быть присвоенно значение

```
object _id = kontr_dg.Rows[i].Cells["id"].Value;
```

на выходе _id = null хотя правая сторона равна значению 2.
Пробывал по другому

```
string _id = kontr_dg.Rows[i].Cells["id"].Value.toString();
```

тоже самое на выходе _id = null. 
Подскажите что делать?
кусок кода где эта строка:

```
MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select id,name,inn,adress,type from kontr",con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
kontr_dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

for (int i = 0; i < kontr_dg.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //Название с ОПФ
    object _id = kontr_dg.Rows[i].Cells["id"].Value;
    string name_opf = core.kontr_name_opf(_id.ToString());
    kontr_dg.Rows[i].Cells["name"].Value = name_opf.ToString();

}
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, kontr_dg - это DataGridView. Если это так, у его свойства Rows[i], еще должна быть ссылка на Row из привязанного DS. Данные надо брать из этого Row. Я сейчас лишен возможности дать пример, если сами не справитесь - дам его утром

Comment: Вероятно, у вас не отключена возможность добавления новой строки пользователем. Или добавьте `kontr_dg.AllowUserToAddRows = false;` или сделайте в цикле `i < kontr_dg.Rows.Count - 1`, чтобы игнорировать фиктивную строку.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том что была возможность добавления новой строки. из-за этого в конце цикла присваивалось значение null.

Верный ответ

```
kontr_dg.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Запрет на добавление новой строки